# How to create a testing branch from main repository excluding specific pull request

Tags: git

I’m working in a project where every day approximately 5 – 10 pull request is being merged to sprint branch every day. Quite often one of them will brake application performance. It is often hard to investigate witch one of them is causing the issue just looking at the code from merged PR’s, so I usually create testing branch by checking out some specific commit and run performance tests from that branch then compering the results. But this solution is time consuming as I often need to checkout lots of times.

Is there an easy way in GIT to create a testing branch excluding specific Pull Request (by branch name would be ideal, or range of commits)?

So on my testing branch I would like to have copy of sprint branch with every PR’s merged but without specific one.

I run through GIT documentation and couldn’t find sets of commands that will let me do it.

Comment: Git doesn't know about your workflow.  Git *can* create branches, though; what you do with those is your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a bad commit automatically, you could use [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect): it will do a binary search through your commit graph to find the "bad" one, which is, in your case, the one that break performance.

Git will do all the checkouts for you and you just have to say if the current commit is GOOD or BAD. Even better: if you can write a script that launch performance tests and say if they are GOOD (return code 0) or BAD (return code !=0), you can automate all the process and just wait for git to give you the faulty commit.

[ProGit - Debugging with Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git)

Comment: Great, thanks for info on that command, missed it when running through documentation. Bisect will definitely help me with that